# Array Manipulation in Crystal Reports 2008 - Not Listing correct result

Tags: arrays, crystal-reports-2008, formula-editor

I'm Trying to List the Values of {Field.Name} using array,But its not Working for me. These are My Code

```
Stringvar Array Name := {Field.Name};
Stringvar cc;
Numbervar i;
For i:= 1 to count(Name) do
(
if cc="" then
(cc:=name[i]);
else
cc:=cc+chrw(13)+name[i];
);
cc;
```

When i Drag this formula to Details Section CR2008.Then Displaying values are one by one on different Details Stection of Preview(Ctrl+R) report. I need its should display all the values in one details section

Comment: what is the data in `{Field.Name}`...I mean how data looks like? which will decide how data displayed in report.

Comment: {field.name} values are
"Rajesh","Ravi","Mathi","Mahesh","Sanjay"..
i want these values should display as one string in on Detail Section

Comment: Mr.Siva, Shall i use Join function for concatination to display all Values of {field.Name}

Comment: yes if field is array... you can use join function.